# Automated WEB SITE deploy using CruiseControl

Tags: msbuild, cruisecontrol.net, aspnet-compiler

I have done some automated deploys for web projects before, but I am having a lot of difficulty setting it up for my web site because there is no .csproj file to reference with MSBuild. I have attempted to use AspNetCompiler but I keep running into roadblocks that prevent this from working. Is anyone experienced with getting CruiseControl to work with web sites, or can this even be done?

Answer (score 0):

Create a solution for this website and use the MSBuild task in cruisecontrol to compile and publish them. Ideally I would create a msbuild file which will compile the solution, archive the currently deployed website and deploy website to the server.

Comment: So basically you're saying that the only way is to convert it into an app with a .csproj file? There's nothing I can use instead of MSBuild that will replicate the Publish feature of VS?

Comment: When you create the website in visual studio, it will create a solution file (*.sln) (website project does not have any .csproj/vbproj file) and use this solution file to compile and publish the website.